# Объединение периодов

Tags: php, timestamp

Очень сложно описать задачу, которую мне нужно решить, но я постараюсь.

Есть промежуток времени (основной): предположим, это начало и конец дня, который по умолчанию красный.

Есть массив (А) небольших промежутков времени, которые помещаются в этот первый промежуток. Они могут быть зелеными и красными.

Нужно наложить этот массив на основной промежуток и получить другой массив (В) промежутков, соблюдая несколько правил:

1. Промежутки массива В должны идти по порядку, соприкасаться, но не пересекаться.
2. В конечном массиве промежутки должны идти в порядке от меньшего к большему, обязательно соприкасаться с соседями, не иметь пустых мест. Первый промежуток должен начинаться с времени начала основного промежутка, последний -- заканчиваться временем конца основного промежутка.
3. Цвета в массиве В должны идти поочередно. То есть не допустимо, чтобы два цвета были рядом. В этом случае, промежутки должны быть объединены.
4. Промежутки массива А имеют приоритет от меньшего к большему. То есть каждый следующий промежуток переопределяет предыдущие другие

Для большей ясности происходящего решил нарисовать диаграмму:

[image: Диаграмма]

Почему спрашиваю: возможно есть готовые инструменты, библиотеки или оптимальные алгоритмы, которые помогут мне решить эту задачу. Не хочу писать костыли и велосипеды.

Зачем это нужно: красный и зеленый цвета означают занятое и свободное время. Цветами обозначил для упрощения.

Дано: PHP. Оперировать можно чем угодно: объектами DateTimeInterface, объектами [League\Period\Period](http://period.thephpleague.com) (который тоже в проекте активно используется) или обычными TimeStamp метками. Я там дальше разберусь, что с этим делать.

Comment: думаю такую кастомную логику нужно писать самому, просто не  понятно, как должно выглядеть предполагаемое решение или библиотека

Comment: задача то вроде не шибко сложная, сложнее чем 80% публикуемых тут вопросов по "переиначить массив", но надо просто составить алгоритм на бумаге, а потом перенести его в код. Библиотеку не найдете, да и смысла нет, тут решение в 15 строк, вероятно

Comment: Мое первое решение пока такое:

1. Разделить основной период на самые мелкие промежутки, основываясь на входных данных массива (А)
2. Найти цвет каждого кусочка, проходя снизу вверх по массиву А и проверяя, попадает ли эта точка в период.
3. Объединить одинаковые цвета.

Решение в лоб, буду пробовать

Comment: так же решал, решил проверить уложусь ли в 15 строк :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока вопрос висел, решил быстренько самому написать решение.

В первую очередь, создаю класс Item с базовым функционалом:

```
class Item
{
    public function __construct($start, $end, $type);
    public function getStart();
    public function getEnd();
    public function getType();
}
```

Следующий класс я пока что решил назвать `Collection`. Он и будет заниматься обработкой периодов:

```
class Collection
{
    /**
     * @param Item $main
     * @param Item[] $items
     */
    public function __construct(Item $main, array $items);
}
```

Внутри конструктора производятся проверки, чтобы каждый item из $items был внутри $main

```
$main->getStart() <= $item->getStart() && $item->getEnd() <= $main->getEnd()
```

После чего элемент $main вставляется в начало массива $items и сохраняется.

Для работы логики не нужно хранить главный элемент отдельно, но желательно проверить, чтобы все элементы были внутри главного периода, чтобы не было неожиданного поведения.

---

Первое, что нужно сделать: разбить главный период на мелкие. То есть собрать все точки начал и концов всех периодов.

Сложно объяснить, но реализация этой логики вот такая:

```
/**
 * @return int[]
 */
public function getPeriodDots()
{
    $dots = [];

    foreach ($this->items as $item) {
        /** @var Item $item */
        $dots = array_filter($dots, function ($dot) use ($item) {
            $inPeriod = $item->getStart() <= $dot && $dot <= $item->getEnd();

            return !$inPeriod;
        });

        $dots[] = $item->getStart();
        $dots[] = $item->getEnd();
    }
    sort($dots);

    return $dots;
}
```

`array_filter` нужен для того, чтобы убрать те точки, которые переопределяет другой период.

---

Промежутки между точками -- новые периоды, тип которых нужно определить.

Чтобы определить тип периода, достаточно взять начало этого периода и пройтись по массиву $items снизу вверх в поиске родительского периода, которому он принадлежит. (Все еще сложно объяснить)

Вот реализация поиска типа:

```
/**
 * @param int $dot
 * @return int
 */
public function getTypeForDot($dot)
{
    /** @var Item[] $items */
    $items = array_reverse($this->items);

    $return = $this->items[0]->getType();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->getStart() <= $dot && $dot < $item->getEnd()) {
            $return = $item->getType();

            break;
        }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

> P.S. Вообще, return можно было сделать и внутри foreach, но PHPStorm
>   ругается, что не хватает return'а в конце. А если оставить просто
>   заглушку `return $this->items[0]->getType();` или `return 0;`, то мы
>   никогда не сможем протестировать эту строчку и достичь 100% покрытия
>   кода тестом.

А вот создание нового массива периодов с указанными типами:

```
/**
 * @param int[] $dots
 * @return Item[]
 */
public function getNewItems($dots)
{
    $startDots = array_slice($dots, 0, -1);
    $endDots = array_slice($dots, 1);

    $newItems = [];

    foreach ($startDots as $i => $start) {
        $end = $endDots[$i];

        $type = $this->getTypeForDot($start);

        $newItems[] = new Item($start, $end, $type);
    }

    return $newItems;
}
```

В итоге мы получим массив новых элементов, которые идут подряд, не пересекаются и не создают пустот. Но...

---

Остается проблема, когда несколько типов идут подряд.

Идея проста: пройтись по массиву и объединить периоды, которые имеют один тип.

Вот мое решение. Думаю, можно сделать и лучше. Если есть идеи -- предлагайте.

```
/**
 * @param Item[] $items
 * @return Item[]
 */
public function optimizePeriods($items)
{
    $newItems = [];
    $item = array_shift($items);
    $start = $item->getStart();
    $end = $item->getEnd();
    $type = $item->getType();

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->getType() === $type) {
            $end = $item->getEnd();
            continue;
        }

        $newItems[] = new Item($start, $end, $type);

        $start = $item->getStart();
        $end = $item->getEnd();
        $type = $item->getType();
    }

    $newItems[] = new Item($start, $end, $type);

    return $newItems;
}
```

---

В итоге нужно просто объединить все, что мы сделали в одну единственную функцию:

```
public function getOptimized()
{
    $dots = $this->getPeriodDots();
    $items = $this->getNewItems($dots);
    return $this->optimizePeriods($items);
}
```

Которая возвращает нам массив элементов, соответствующих нашей задаче.

---

В итоге получилось аккуратное решение, хорошо тестируемое, не зависимое от фреймворка.

Полное решение с 100% покрытием кода тестом выложил в [gist](https://gist.github.com/vtvz/09e1ca69e7d925027750b0157e0244a8). Решил скрыть namespaces, но суть от этого не меняется.

Если будет востребовано, могу сделать отдельную библиотеку.